# chrony takes many minutes to read refclocks after boot

Tags: ntp, timekeeping

I'm looking to provide precise time to a Raspberry Pi 4 without internet via a UBLOX GNSS module that sends NMEA sentences over UART and PPS to a GPIO.

15 NMEA sentences (ZDA, GGA, RMC, GSA, GBS, GSV) per second arrive at `/dev/serial0`. These come in as soon as I boot up which I verified with `gpsmon -n`. `gpsd` is the service that takes care of processing these.

The PPS pulses also arrive right after boot which I verified with `sudo ppscheck /dev/pps0`.

I have configured chrony by creating `/etc/chrony/conf.d/gps.conf` with the content:

```
refclock SHM 0 refid NMEA offset 0.1 precision 0.2 poll 0
refclock PPS /dev/pps0 refid PPS lock NMEA poll 0 trust prefer
log refclocks
```

I have experimented a lot with the options in the config file: delay, offset, precision, trust, noselect, prefer and lock, to no avail.

I've left `/etc/chrony/chrony.conf` the way it always was:

```
# Welcome to the chrony configuration file. See chrony.conf(5) for more
# information about usable directives.

# Include configuration files found in /etc/chrony/conf.d.
confdir /etc/chrony/conf.d

# Use Debian vendor zone.
pool 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst

# Use time sources from DHCP.
sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp

# Use NTP sources found in /etc/chrony/sources.d.
sourcedir /etc/chrony/sources.d

# This directive specify the location of the file containing ID/key pairs for
# NTP authentication.
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys

# This directive specify the file into which chronyd will store the rate
# information.
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift

# Save NTS keys and cookies.
ntsdumpdir /var/lib/chrony

# Uncomment the following line to turn logging on.
#log tracking measurements statistics

# Log files location.
logdir /var/log/chrony

# Stop bad estimates upsetting machine clock.
maxupdateskew 100.0

# This directive enables kernel synchronisation (every 11 minutes) of the
# real-time clock. Note that it can’t be used along with the 'rtcfile' directive.
rtcsync

# Step the system clock instead of slewing it if the adjustment is larger than
# one second, but only in the first three clock updates.
makestep 1 3

# Get TAI-UTC offset and leap seconds from the system tz database.
# This directive must be commented out when using time sources serving
# leap-smeared time.
leapsectz right/UTC
```

The issue is: after rebooting, `chrony` doesn't receive data from `gpsd` or the PPS. I've verified this by running `chronyc sources` (It shows hyphens for both in the `LastRx` column.) and `sudo tail -f /var/log/chrony/refclocks.log` (no updates there).

After several minutes (5-20) chrony starts getting time from `gpsd` and PPS and updates the system time a few seconds after that (verified the same way as explained in the previous paragraph). Sometimes it's different and `chrony` takes several more minutes to read the PPS after getting time from `gpsd`. I've tried rebooting many times and the result is always the same. Data from the GNSS module comes in immediately and can be accessed with `gpsmon -n` and `ppscheck` right after boot. **Then, why does `chrony` need over 5 minutes to get the same information?**

By the way, after resetting the system time with `sudo date +%T -s "12:00:00"`, and `sudo systemctl reastart chrony` there's no issue: `chrony` updates the system time within seconds.